# Web Source into NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How could I access a website and turn components of the website into strings.  For example taking information from Facebook posts. I have done a little searching but can't find any good tutorials or anything useful.

Comment: So parse the HTML, write to a file the app can access, then what?

Comment: Download the web page you want to parse into an `NSString` with `+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error`, then pass it to an HTML parser and extract the element(s) you're interested in.

Comment: The other approach is to use DOM and XPATH.  You need to go do some research. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at this tutorial. It should get you more familiar on the subject and start you off on the right track.

As it states at the beginning of the tutorial...

> How to Parse HTML on iOS
>
> Let’s say you want to find some information inside a web page and
>   display it in a custom way in your app. This technique is called
>   “scraping.” Let’s also assume you’ve thought through alternatives to
>   scraping web pages from inside your app, and are pretty sure that’s
>   what you want to do. Well then you get to the question – how can you
>   programmatically dig through the HTML and find the part you’re looking
>   for, in the most robust way possible? Believe it or not, regular
>   expressions won’t cut it! Well, in this tutorial you’ll find out how!
>   You’ll get hands-on experience with parsing HTML into an Objective-C
>   data model that your apps can use.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you could summarize the linked page. As it stands, this answer will be useless if the page moves or disappears.